# Thunderbird-like template system in another email client?

Tags: email, thunderbird, lotus-notes, templates, postbox

I hope this is the right place to ask this kind of question - I really am not entirely sure.

I'm looking for an email client that has a template system similar to that of Thunderbird/Postbox. Unfortunately, there are simply too many bugs in the Mozilla/Thunderbird-based clients, and it's causing too many issues for my business.

Such an email client would need to have all the similar features, though.

Does anyone know if such an email client exists?

*Side: I quite like the concept of IBM Notes (my mother used it back when it was still Lotus), and I'd be willing to pay for that, but it doesn't seem to have the same kind of template system.*

Answer (score 1):

I am not overly familiar with Thunderbird, but it is possible to create Stationary in Lotus Notes. More details here.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.notes85.help.doc%2Fmail_stationery_t.html

There is a free version you can play with (mail functionality may not fully work).

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ls/dominodesigner/

Notes is more then a mail client though, so if all you want is just the mail then it would probably be over kill.

Comment: In Thunderbird, one simply creates an email, saves it as a template (with attachments and applicable formatting). Then, when it is needed, one would simply go to the Templates folder double click on the one needed, edit (if necessary), add the email address of the recipient, and hit send. Is this personal stationery the same thing?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how the stationary works in IBM Notes. I use it all the time for my weekly reports, etc.